# How to handle multiple file upload using same js function - jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Need to make the file upload function upload multiple files at a go. The file upload works fine if uploading just ONE file at a time and upload is done in chunk...

Right now, there is need to expand the form capability to allow multiple file fields which allow user to make multiple selection of files and handling this using a loop within the js function. I tried but it isn't working for me. Not been able to get the js function to work with selection of multiple files. When more than one file is uploaded, it conflicts with each other and none of the file get uploaded successfully.

```js
(function($) {
  var fileReader = {};
  var file = {};
  var slice_size = 1000 * 1024;

  function triggerUpload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fileReader = new FileReader();
    file = document.querySelector('#my_file_upload').files[0];
    fileUploadHandler(0);
  }
  
  $('#form_upload_submit').on('click', triggerUpload);

  function fileUploadHandler(start) {
    var next_slice = start + slice_size + 1;
    var blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);

    fileReader.onloadend = function(event) {
      if (event.target.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) {
        return;
      }

      var form_data = {
        file_data: event.target.result,
        file: file.name,
        file_type: file.type
      };

      $.ajax({
        url: "server_upload.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: form_data,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Upload failed');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          alert('success : ' + file.name);
          var size_done = start + slice_size;
          var percent_done = Math.floor((size_done / file.size) * 100);

          if (next_slice < file.size) {
            $('#progress_display').html(percent_done + '% Uploaded');
            fileUploadHandler(next_slice);
          } else {
            $('#progress_display').html('Upload Completed!');
          }
        }
      });
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```php
<?php    
  $upload_dir = '../upl/';
  $file_path =  $upload_dir . $_POST['file'];
  $file_data = decodeFile( $_POST['file_data'] );
  file_put_contents( $file_path, $file_data, FILE_APPEND );

  function decodeFile($data) 
  {
    $data = explode( ';base64,', $data );
    $data = base64_decode( $data[1] );
    return $data;
  } 
?>
```

Would be pleased to get some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: @rory May I ask what your revision of the code was?

Comment: Sure, I formatted the code in the question to have a consistent tab width and line breaks. You can review the changes I made by clicking the 'edited 1 hour ago' link.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the code formatting! But that isn't the help I seek.. All the same, appreciated.. LOL!!!

Comment: I know. I was making your code readable so that your question is easier to read